# Delay angular directive template from compiling until function is complete

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-directive

I have an angular directive which displays an image on my page. However, this image is determined by the value in a querystring in the URL:

```
app.directive('myDirective', function(myService) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        scope: true,
        link: function($scope, element, attrs) {

            var myImage = myService.getParam();

            if (myImage == AA3) {
                $scope.myImage = 'YAHOO';
            }
            else {
                $scope.myImage = 'capitalone';
            }

        },
        template : '<img src="/resources/{{myImage}}.png" />'
    };
});
```

The problem with the above is that i can see 2 http requests:

```
1. http://www.mydom.net/resources/{{myImage}}.png
2. http://www.mydom.net/resources/YAHOO.png
```

How can i delay the compile of template until myImage contains a value?

Comment: use `ng-src` instead of `src` on your `img` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`ng-src`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc) should do the trick  ~~

`template : '<img ng-src="/resources/{{myImage}}.png" />'`

Answer (score 1):

use ng-src instead of src.

```
<img ng-src="/resources/{{myImage}}.png" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Use ng-src instead of src

```
template : '<img ng-src="/resources/{{myImage}}.png" />'
```